# app crashes in managed object context in core data in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, ios7

hi friends i am working with core data .when i run the project it crashes with the following message

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name'Ad' "
```

The following code i used

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
ads = [NSArray new];
[self fetchAllAds];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [ads count];
}
-(NSArray *)fetchAllAds {
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ad" 
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
NSError *error = nil;
ads = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return ads;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShoppingCart";
ShoppingCart *cell = (ShoppingCart*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath];
Ad *list = [ads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"The string is %@",list.data);
cell.addesc.text=list.data;
cell.adId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",list.adId];
cell.adstatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",list.state];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: The error message is really clear telling you what'S wrong. Some times it makes sense to check return values of methods.

Comment: You have no entity called 'Ad' in your core data model

Answer (score -1):

I would change in viewDidLoad the statement `[super viewDidLoad];`to be the first. Everything else looks fine to me. Hope this helps

Comment: The order/position of the `viewDidLoad` call has no relevance in the problem that the OP is trying to resolve here. If you have code-related suggestions that don't actually answer the question, please consider writing a comment on the question instead.